# Trying to make a 'friend request' signal in django but getting FOREIGN KEY constraint failed - Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-signals

I am trying to make a feature where a student can send a teacher friend request and if the teacher accepts it, the student should get added to a **students' list** present in the teacher's profile model and the teacher should get added to the **teachers' list** present in the student's profile. To handle and store this relationship between sender and receiver I have made a different model **(Relationship)** and signal. But while the operation is being carried out by the signal I get this error

```
FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
```

Please look at my code below and correct me on what should I do to get rid of this error.

**teacher's profile model (TeacherDetail)**

```
class TeacherDetail(models.Model):
   user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
   student = models.ManyToManyField(CustomUser, blank=True, related_name='students') # this is the student's list
```

**student's profile (StudentDetail)**

```
class StudentDetail(models.Model):
   user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
   teacher = models.ManyToManyField(CustomUser, blank=True, related_name='teachers') # this is the teacher's list
```

**model that stores the sender and the receiver (Relationship)**

```
STATUS_CHOICES=(
    ('sent', 'sent'),
    ('pending', 'pending'),
    ('accepted', 'accepted')
)


class Relationship(models.Model):
    
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, editable=False, default=uuid.uuid4)
    
    sender = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='sender') # the student
    
    receiver = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='reciever') # the teacher
    
    status = models.CharField(max_length= 10, choices=STATUS_CHOICES)

    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=False)
```

**signals**

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Relationship)
def handle_student_to_teacher_req(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    
    student_sender = instance.sender 
    teacher_receiver = instance.receiver
    
    if instance.status == 'accepted':
        
        print(f"student_sender {student_sender}")
        print(f"teacher_receiver {teacher_receiver}")
        
        student_sender.teachers.add(teacher_receiver.id)
        teacher_receiver.students.add(student_sender.id)
        
        student_sender.save()
        teacher_receiver.save()
```

I am using signals for the first time so please help by correcting the code above

**Update**

**the entire traceback error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rickb\Envs\schoolies-backend-env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\rickb\Envs\schoolies-backend-env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response        
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\rickb\Envs\schoolies-backend-env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 683, in wrapper
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\rickb\Envs\schoolies-backend-env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 133, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\rickb\Envs\schoolies-backend-env\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py", line 62, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\rickb\Envs\schoolies-backend-env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 242, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\rickb\Envs\schoolies-backend-env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1888, in change_view      
    return self.changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
  File "C:\Users\rickb\Envs\schoolies-backend-env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 46, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\rickb\Envs\schoolies-backend-env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 133, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\rickb\Envs\schoolies-backend-env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1745, in changeform_view  
    return self._changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
  File "C:\Users\rickb\Envs\schoolies-backend-env\lib\site-packages\django\db\transaction.py", line 255, in __exit__
    connection.commit()
  File "C:\Users\rickb\Envs\schoolies-backend-env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\rickb\Envs\schoolies-backend-env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 291, in commit
    self._commit()
  File "C:\Users\rickb\Envs\schoolies-backend-env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 267, in _commit
    return self.connection.commit()
  File "C:\Users\rickb\Envs\schoolies-backend-env\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\rickb\Envs\schoolies-backend-env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 267, in _commit
    return self.connection.commit()
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
```

Comment: Please include the error traceback in your question.

Comment: @HåkenLid I have added the traceback please check now

Answer (score 0):

I made a mistake in assigning the models in the relationship model. After I made the below change the error got rectified.

```
class Relationship(models.Model):
    
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, editable=False, default=uuid.uuid4)
    
    sender = models.ForeignKey(StudentDetail, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='sender') # the student
    
    receiver = models.OneToOneField(TeacherDetail, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='reciever') # the teacher
    
    status = models.CharField(max_length= 10, choices=STATUS_CHOICES)

    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=False)
```